# What is the analytical extension of $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I can prove the singularity of $f(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ at $z=0$ is a removable one. Now I want to explicit its analytical extension, how can I do that?

**Note**: Since $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1$, if I put $f(0)=1$, I can turn this function at a continuous one. Is this function analytical?

Comment: Yes. $$f(z) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} z^{2n}.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer it's true, thank you!

Comment: Mathematicians use the name "sinc" for a function $f(x)$ that's $\sin(x)/x$ for $x$ nonzero, and $1$ for$x=0$.